# Eigenvalues of $p(A$)

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of a matrix $A$. I am trying to show that all the eigenvalues of $p(A)$ are $p(\lambda)$ where $p(x)$ is any polynomial.

I have been able to show that $p(\lambda)$ is an eigenvalue of $p(A)$. But how to show that these will be the only eigenvalues?

For instance, if eigenvalues of $A$ are $1$ and $-1$.

Then I know that 1 is an eigenvalue of $A^2$ but how to show that there is no other eigenvalue?

Comment: try the Jordan form.

Comment: Is there any other way?

Comment: The Schur form. The accepted answer assumes that this can be done.

Comment: There is no space in eigenvalue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume $A$ is a complex $n \times n$ matrix.

Then $A$ is similar to an upper triangular matrix $D$ whose diagonal coefficients are (in order) $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n$ the eigen values of $A$ (with repetition), so there exist $P$ an invertible (complex) matrix such that $A = P^{-1} D P$.

Then, writing $p = \sum_k \alpha_k X^k$ we have

$$
p(A) = \sum_k \alpha_k (P^{-1} D P)^k = \sum_k \alpha_k P^{-1} D^k P = P^{-1} \left(\sum_k \alpha_k D^k \right) P = P^{-1} p(D) P.
$$

Now it suffices to see that $p(D)$ is upper diagonal and that its diagonal coefficients are $p(\lambda_1), \dots, p(\lambda_n)$. Indeed, since $D$ is upper triangular, $D^k$ is also upper diagonal and its diagonal coefficients are $\lambda_1^k, \dots, \lambda_n^k$, and the result follows by linearity.

Since $p(A)$ is similar to an upper diagonal matrix whose diagonal coefficients are $p(\lambda_1), \dots, p(\lambda_n)$, the spectrum of $p(A)$ is $\{p(\lambda_1), \dots, p(\lambda_n)\}$.

Hope this helps!

Comment: So there is a real matrix A such that $\lambda$ is an eigen value of A but $\lambda$$^2$ is not an eigen value of A$^2$?

Comment: So there is a real matrix such that $\lambda$ is an eigen value of A but $\lambda$$^2$ is not an eigen value of A$^2$

Comment: No there is not. From the answer that I have given, if $A$ is a real (or complex) matrix then $\text{sp} (p(A)) = p(\text{sp} (A))$ so take $p = X^2$, you get that $\text{sp}(A^2) = \text{sp} (A) ^2$, where for a set $Y$, i use the (not so standard) notation $Y^2 = \{y^2 : y \in Y\}$ (be careful, this notation is not at all standard and should not be confused with the cartesian product notation). So if $\lambda$ is an eigen value of $A$, $\lambda^2$ is an eigen value of $A^2$.

Comment: Note that you also proved this side of the set equality in your question, i.e. that $p(\text{sp}(A)) \subset \text{sp} (p(A))$

Comment: This thing..that a matrix is similar to an upper triangular matrix..Doesn't it hold in only the matrices with complex entries?

Comment: Yes, this only works in the space of complex $n \times n$ matrices, meaning that the invertible matrix $P$ I have introduced is a complex matrix. But any real matrix is a complex matrix (since $\mathbb R \subset \mathbb C$) so you can use this theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\alpha$ be an eigenvalue of $p(A)$. Then $W=N(p(A)-\alpha I)$ is nontrivial. Let $g(x)=p(x)-\alpha,$ then $g(x)$ annhilates $A$ when restricted to $W$. So, minimal polynomial of $A$ restricted to $W$, $m_W(x)$ divides  $g(x)$. But $m_W(x)$ divides the minimal polynomial, $m(x)$ of $A$. Hence $m(x)$ and $g(x)$ have a common zero.

**Note:** $W$ is an $A$ invariant subspace.